# How do I design system for bilingual use?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I need CMS where every piece of content, every blog article or about us section would exist in two synchronized universes – language 1(for example English) and language 2 (for example Russian).

With rarely updated content (about us, contacts) it's easy – make a translation once, put it in array, connect with i18n.

However I'm struggling with ways of do it with blog-like articles which editors will write. Do I need to make an additional tab with language 2 that mirrors the structure of content? How to make them synchronized – how to handle this in database?

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [apostrophe-workflow](https://npmjs.org/apostrophe-workflow) module, which was created for this purpose. The documentation covers how to configure it for multiple locales (languages) and export content between them.